# Is this equation $\frac{k+8}{x^2}+\frac{6}{x}+k=0 $ still a quadratic?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am able to solve $ax^2+bx+c=0$.  However, when the $"x^2" and "x"$ go to the denominator, I am stuck. Like this question $\frac{k+8}{x^2}+\frac{6}{x}+k=0   $

Comment: Multiply all sides by the LCD of the denominators. Then you end up with a quadratic and solve it. Just make sure to check for extraneous solutions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is $$\frac{k+8}{x^2}+\frac{6}{x}+k=0$$ is the same as$$ (k+8)(1/x)^2 + 6 (1/x)+k=0$$ which is quadratic in the variable $(1/x)$

You may also multiply by $x^2$ to get  a new quadratic equation.

Answer (score 2):

You know that $x \neq 0$ because you are dividing by it in the problem.  Multiply by $x^2$ and you have a standard quadratic form.

Answer (score 1):

Substituting $$t=\frac{1}{x}$$ then you will get $$(k+8)t^2+6t+k=0$$